# Getting the CPU time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time

Is there a way to get the time a piece of JavaScript actually runs on the CPU, like with the `clock()` and `getrusage()` functions in C? Using the normal `Date()` way only gives the wall time, and for performance measurements the CPU time would be much more useful.

Note that I'm not looking for profiling tools, I want to reduce system noise for automated testing and not optimize specific functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. `Date` is the only thing the standard JavaScript library provides.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers, notably WebKit based ones, have Javascript profiling built in (e.g. in the Web Inspector). This should be even more useful than `clock()`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really suitable in my case: I want to reduce system noise for automatic testing and not optimize specific functions. I guess I should have made that more clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be old, but I bumped here. So might as well share what I used.

There has now been a lot of updates with nodejs, and Node.js create a performance API [NodeJS Performance](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html).

```
var t0 = performance.now()
doSomeFunction()
var t1 = performance.now()
console.log( `performance: ${t1-t0}` )
```